# Cast an array to a struct and vice-versa in c

Tags: c, arrays, struct, casting

Let be the following struct:

```
typedef struct { 
    int x;
    int y;
} st;
```

I can "cast" an int array to a struct st:

```
st z;
int t[2];
t[0] = 0;
t[1] = 1;
z = *(st*)(t);
printf("%d,%d\n", z.x, z.y);
```

Then the output is, as excepted:

```
0,1
```

But i cant cast a struct st to an int array:

```
st z = {0, 1};
int t[2];
t = *(int*)(&z);
```

since an array cant be assigned after initialization.

So, how may i achieve this ?
Thanks for helping me.

Comment: The basis of your "cast" is a violation of strict aliasing. And thus the behavior of your program is undefined.

Comment: @StoryTeller Only because the struct does not contain an array `int[2]` as one of its members. The ideal solution seems to be `typedef union{ struct{ int x; int y; } int array[2];
} st;`

Comment: @Lundin - You know, I never got [that bullet in standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5p7). If the struct itself contained an additional member `int[2]`, what access would be legal?

Comment: @StoryTeller "An object shall have its stored value accessed only by" ... "an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its members". An array is an aggregate, as is a struct. So come to think of it, this code looks safe as far as strict aliasing is concerned.

Comment: I think the main concern here is alignment/struct padding.

Comment: @Lundin - That certainly changes how I view strict aliasing if the bullet makes it okay strict-aliasing-wise...

Comment: @StoryTeller GCC doesn't like the cast though. I guess that's what it boils down to, since GCC is the only compiler dysfunctional enough to abuse strict aliasing UB for optimization purposes.

Comment: On the other hand, GCC also whines about strict aliasing when I change the struct to `typedef struct { int x[2]; } st;` I would be inclined to regard this as a bug in GCC.

Comment: @StoryTeller the standard's unclear on whether it's permitted to "work around" strict aliasing by casting to pointer to union type containing both types ... my interpretation is that it isn't.  Many such strict aliasing issues are being addressed for C2X

Comment: @M.M It's not a "work around", the strict aliasing rules has an explicit exception for aggregate/union types that contains a compatible type among its members. The compatible type here would be anything of array type `int [2]`, including signed/unsigned/qualified versions of that array. Thus a pointer to any form of "aggregate" (be it an array, struct or union) containing a `int[2]` (or allowed compatible versions) can safely be used to access the data of the original array. Really not much room for interpretation.

Comment: Apart from that, it is obvious to anyone who work with real-world applications that the UB cases related to the "strict aliasing rule" cannot be allowed to be UB, because well-defined type punning is in what makes C different from the animals. This is a language defect that needs to be fixed, and compilers should not be allowed to cut corners because of the strict aliasing rule.

Answer (score 2):

```
z = *(st*)(t);
```

Syntactically this code will compile (assignation to `struct`) and may give the expected or unexpected result because it violates strict aliasing requirement.

```
t = *(int*)(&z);
```

This piece of code is syntactically incorrect for multiple reasons and thus compilation itself would fail. First of all, you can't assign to arrays, secondly, you are assigning a pointer to `int` to an `int` array. A better bet would be to use `memcpy` or `union` instead. Though I would suggest member by member copy.

Comment: `t = *(int*)(&z);` is syntactically correct, but a constraint violation because `t` is not a modifiable lvalue

Comment: int t[] = *(int *)(&z)  is in accordance with what i understand but is an invalid initialization.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems here that need to be solved. Your concern for how to assign values to an array in run-time is one. "Strict aliasing" during pointer conversions is another.

Regarding strict aliasing, you are not allowed to access an array of type `int [2]` as if it was a `struct { int x; int y; }`. Formally this could be regarded as undefined behavior. Some compilers, most notably gcc, may do weird optimizations on such code.

To solve these issues, as well as the array assignment issue, I recommend that you change your code to this:

```
typedef union 
{ 
  struct
  {
    int x;
    int y;
  }; //Anonymous structure, C11 feature, won't compile on old legacy compilers.
  int array [2];
} st;
```

This solves all aliasing issues and you can now copy these "arrays" with simple assignment:

```
s1 s1 = ...;
s1 s2 = s2;
```

And the code

```
st z;
int t[2] = {1, 1};
z = *(st*)t;
```

is now fine and well-defined behavior (*).

---

(*) C11 6.5/7 :

> "An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue
>   expression that has one of the following types:" /--/
>
> - "an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its members"