# Type cast from an array to a structure

Tags: c, casting

I recently read a code with type cast as this:

```
#define PBIS ((const SectionBootInt_t * const) PRIMARY_PAGE->bootInternal)
```

Here, PRIMARY_PAGE->bootInternal is an array, uint64_t bootInternal[0x4], member of some structure;
And SectionBootInt_t is a structure, as below:

```
typedef struct
{
    uint64_t Previous_Ver;
    uint64_t Current_Ver;
} SectionBootInt_t;
```

So I don't see what is the casting doing here. Could someone help me understand? Thanks!

Regards,

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Cast an array to a struct in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42268701)

Comment: generally, such cast results in violation of strict aliasing rules thus UB. More context is needed

Comment: @Andy Sukowski-Bang Yes, it explained what I am confused about. Thanks!